# How to discuss an example?

Tags: support, documentation

I have come upon several examples that I thought could be improved, but did not know how *best* to improve them.

I'll take case of the C++ [Converting upper-case to lower-case and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/488/stdstring/1776/converting-upper-case-to-lower-case-and-vice-versa#t=201607231343095814478).

The example, as originally provided, shows of how to apply `::tolower` and `::toupper`. The recommendation on how to apply `::tolower` and `::toupper` are good, but unfortunately those functions are *extremely* limited: they really only work for ASCII and close-to-ASCII alphabets (German does not work because of its esset).

I could not find how to discuss the limitations of the proposed methods; and in the end settled for writing up a disclaimer at the top of the example to explain the limits of it. It seems it went fine here...

... but it's unclear how well that'll hold in the future.

So where should one comment/discuss a particular example?

Comment: The disclaimer seems fine to me. Especially if it links to an example of another way to do it that avoids the limitations.

Comment: @CodyGray: no example to propose; I suppose ICU could be mentioned here (or maybe Boost wrapper's?), but that's really something I am not expert on and I would have liked to have a discussion about...

Comment: There is a discussion room dedicated to **C++ Documentation** https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118051/c-documentation

Comment: You're right, there is not an obvious good solution. Sounds like something that you'd want to ask a community of experts about, in order to solicit answers. Oh, if only there were a high-quality place to do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm of the mind that every documentation language should have a more long-term and slow moving discussion option behind it.

**Each example should be good, but there should be a resource for people who are working on it to discuss problems with it.**

"Chat" is transient for this, and the overhead of the chat interface is mostly a burden, and its real-time nature is *too* real-time and transient for this sort of thing.

At present, there's only one way to give "out of band" feedback on a piece and that's a "needs enhancement review", and that's simply not good enough.

Especially as there's no way to respond to those statements, and "dismiss" is the only option... that's simply not useful.

Some edits I'd make, but it would simply resort to edit-warring, reverting the edit back to somebody else's opinion, and then somebody else reverting it the other way again.

**It needs a "Discuss this example" section** where the nuance can be fleshed out and notes made like *"hey, this thing you're telling users to do, please, stop doing that, its not good anymore"*.

However, burdening end readers with mountains of "here's a feature that exists, and you can use, but shouldn't because it will take your feet off" is likely to achieve the wrong result.

You want to present only the **best** options, and let the crappier ones stay hidden such that only intrepid explorers will find them talked about in the discussion section of an example/topic.

Answer (score -1):

There is a discussion room dedicated to **C++ Documentation** https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118051/c-documentation

The hope is to help one another figure out how to solve issues like this.

Comment: Awful. We shouldn't have to use chat just to figure out how to use a fundamental feature of the site, any more than we should have to communicate by leaving comments on each others' unrelated answers. And everything that gets talked about in chat is basically buried forever. When I go to the documentation, I don't see any of the insight that was tossed about in chat about how to properly convert Unicode strings.

Comment: @CodyGray The question is "How to discuss an example?". Do you not think mentioning the chat feature is a suitable answer to the question that was asked?

Comment: No, I don't think it's a suitable answer. I mean, yes, technically it is an answer to the question, so I'm not saying you should delete it. But it is a bad solution. Not sure if you're new to Meta or not, but technical validity is not the only criteria for evaluating answers here.

Comment: @CodyGray So what do you think is a **good solution** to the question "How to discuss an example?"

Comment: If I had a good solution, I would have posted an answer. Documentation is fundamentally broken, and this is a relatively minor reason that is rather low on my list of concerns at the moment. I feel like you are getting defensive about your answer, and I don't really understand why. If you want to disagree with my objections, then feel free. But voicing an objection doesn't obligate me to come up with a different idea.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm just trying to understand exactly what your objection to my answer is. Otherwise it just sounds a bit like you are taking your frustration with Documentation in general out on my answer.

Comment: @CodyGray OP asked how we could **discus** an example. I suggested the **chat** feature. It just seems like a good answer to the question asked. If **chatting** is not a good way to **discus** then what is?

Comment: If anything, I am taking out my frustration with chat in general out on your answer. No, I don't like Docs either, but for different reasons. Anyway: (1) I think it is problematic to suggest that we have to use chat in order to make docs work. This sets a bad precedent. We don't have to use chat to make Q&A work. We don't have to use Q&A to make chat work. Why can't Docs be self-contained? (2) Matthieu is looking for a long-term solution to this problem, as it will come up over and over again. Chat is not sustainable for this, for reasons I've already outlined.

Comment: @CodyGray Well I posted this answer because I too feel that Docs is not working well and I want to be able to discus the problems with other people. Docs is not going to fix itself and I have no idea how we can improve things without communicating. Docs is advertized as "collaborative development" after all.